# Rails: setting association object vs. setting association id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm following the "Agile Web Development with Rails" book and trying to copy a Products price to the LineItem. Overriding the setter on LineItem seems to be the appropriate choice. However, as so often in Rails, having two generated setters makes the exercise non-trivial:

```
  def product_id=(product_id)
    product = Product.find(product_id)
    write_attribute(:price, product.price)
    write_attribute(:product_id, product_id)
  end

  def product=(product)
    self.product_id = product.id #wtf? why isn't this the default?
  end
```

This code works as expected, whether I set the object or it's id, in both cases the price gets copied. What makes me wonder:

Why isn't this delegate working without having to override "product=(..)"? Strangely without removing "self" it will not work, apparently it will not delegate to "product_id=()"...

Comment: There's an obvious optimization to my example by delegating from 'product_id=' to 'product=' instead of vice-versa. This way the product does not have to be loaded again if it's already passed into 'product='.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `product=` with the default implementation will not call `product_id=`.  It simply uses `write_attribute` just as you have done in your overridden `product_id=` method.

Comment: Upvote for answering my question, downvote for Rails for breaking it's own dogma. Where's DRY if they don't even get simple delegates right?

Comment: I wouldn't blame this on Rails/ActiveRecord.  What you really need is an observer on the product_id attribute, which isn't provided out of the box AFAIK.

Comment: I assume as this is happening completely inside the line_item class a callback inside line item would do. Anyway, considering a potential test case this would not lead to the behavior I expect - I would basically have to save the record before the price attribute gets updated. IMHO this is a scenario setters were intended for - allowing a hook to implement code related to an attribute change, so I would expect the price changing directly after I set the product.

Answer (score -1):

### Your Model Isn't Optimal

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, or why you're trying to do it, but it seems to me that at least part of your problem is that your model relationship is wrong—or at least sub-optimal.

Look at it this way:

1. A Product should have a price. That's logically a property of a Product.
2. A LineItem is really a *presentation* of a Product and its properties, and perhaps some other related data.

I realize you're following some tutorial, so perhaps the tutorial is trying to make some specific point. However, in a real-world application, a normalized database shouldn't be copying data from model-to-model or object-to-object; a price should have exactly one place to live, and should be referenced (rather than copied) from other tables.

### Model Considerations

If you follow my advice, then a Product has an ID, a LineItem has a reference to a product stored in a product_id field, and you access the price through LineItem.product.price, or set up delegation if you don't want to violate the Law of Demeter for this common use case.

This may not help you with your tutorial, but using an ActiveRecord relation certainly makes more sense to me than copying values from one table to another. YMMV.

Comment: From a database design perspective you're correct, but in reality the line item reflects a part of a customers order with the price at the moment the customer ordered it. Consider the outrage when between the moment the customer ordered the product and the moment the shop sends the bill somebody raises the price.

Comment: @joerx You certainly have other options: store the current cart with the current price, store the price in the session, use an observer to modify some other model, and so on. Since you didn't post the rest of your context, one is forced to assume that you're making some other model aware of Product internals; this is generally a bad idea, but YMMV. Good luck!

Comment: 1. - since when does using a public attribute mean being aware of internals? That's why it's public - for others to use it. 2. - why do something simple if we can make it complicated? - I don't see how sessions or observers would help me to even solve the problem in the first place. All I want a shopping basket as a persistent and historically consistent record of a customers order and a bit of deliberate denormalization (one could even argue about that) does the trick simply and nicely.